# Our Unofficial Facebook Page

Tags: discussion, promotion

Hi Guys here is our Unofficial Facebook page

[Movies & TV Facebook Page Link](https://www.facebook.com/pages/Movies-and-TV/216914131767125?skip_nax_wizard=true)

This is just for the purposes of increasing our traffic,  so please help to make it popular by spreading it to your friends. There is no restriction setting, so anybody can post it there.

**Every suggestion is appreciable.**

Comment: I wonder, is there any direct and obvious link to M&TV on the Facebook page? Maybe there is, but I didn't find one in the first few seconds, but then again I don't have any Facebook experience (yes, I live on Mars), maybe this isn't allowed or approved.

Comment: @ChristianRau added direct link in About page also

Comment: So wait.. is this going to be like meta.meta.movies.stackexchange.com?

Comment: @BobbyAlexander Its just for promotional purpose on social network (Unofficialy). Their is nothing like meta in it.

Answer (score 2):

Why don't we post the day's, week's, month's hot questions on that page. That will attract more attention to the site itself. Extending the same idea, we can feature a list of "*All Time Best*" questions and answers too.

This will just be a small step in the direction. Going ahead, I think there can be a ton of things that we can do on the FB page to promote and refine the community. Feeling excited!!

Comment: That is tough work to do, because its an unofficial fb page so it has to be done manually (by me). And these days i left less time to do so.

Comment: Maybe you can share "_Post of the Week_" to begin with. That shouldn't be very hard, a post a week.

Comment: Yesterday, i have just tried adding rss feeds for the page from  M&TV with no success. But, will set something up soon.

Comment: @AnkitSharma: Good luck and godspeed.

Comment: RSS feed has been added it will post 5 new question each day, lets see the response.

Answer (score 2):

While I understand that it's an **unofficial** *Facebook* page, I still think that the rather officially sounding name of *"Movies & TV"* and the goal of representing [movies.se] to the *Facebook* world comes with the responsibility to stay as objective and true to the site as possible.

Having said that, some parts on this *Facebook* page (like the shared links, or the "likes") make me wonder if those are the views of [movies.se] or *Ankit Sharma*'s (or where the difference between both is).

Comment: Some old post are just to communicate with people to attract them and some are for promotion of area51 proposal. Will try to represent [tag:movies.se] more onwards.

Comment: @AnkitSharma Instead of e.g. promoting *Indian Language & Usage* or *Hinduism* you might want to promote the more movies-related *Home Theater & Audio* proposal. ;-)

Comment: @AnkitSharma No problem with communication, but I'm not sure *Wolverine* is [movies.se]'s favourite X-Men character. (Ok, bad example, since *Wolverine* is probably *everybody*'s favourite X-Men character, anyway, but I guess you get what I'm after) ;-) Likewise does [movies.se] not really have "favourite questions", or at least only in terms of upvotes or view counts.

Comment: @AnkitSharma But those are just hints, I don't want to dictate how you manage your *Facebook* account either.

Comment: I got your point. The Wolverine was just like a current affair topic so shared it. Anyways thinking to give the page little more time and more efforts.

Comment: Your intention are all appear good to me and will appreciate advices.

Comment: RSS Feeds has been set for the page, it will automatically update newest 5 question per day

Comment: @AnkitSharma Cool, it also seem to have the *TomatoBot*.

Comment: I have removed tomatobot because free feeds are only 300, after that i have to pay. So want to utilize all 300 for our site only. Will search for other rss feed provider.

Answer (score 1):

Great Job Ankit. We appreciate your efforts. I am not getting why Stack Exchange does not starts official facebook pages of it's network sites still. I worry there can people make fake facebook pages of sites. I have made request for making facebook pages for the same. But this is not getting much attention. And we can like that page on facebook and spread our word.

https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/165560/can-we-have-facebook-like-option-for-each-network-site-of-stack-exchange

Comment: Most of the people on SO Meta doesn't like FB. So its the case of disapproval to your request.But we can at-least try with this unofficial page to promote by sharing it with friends.

Comment: `this is not getting much attention` Untrue. Question received significant amount of vote-downs.

Comment: What exactly would you discuss on a Facebook page of a site that asks questions?

Comment: Just for advertisement/ pusblishing the existence of website.